# GIMP transparency by brightness

Tags: gimp

At the moment I have a black and white texture image (e.g. of a paper texture), and want to turn the white area transparent.

However, simply selecting by colour and making the whitest area transparent gives something that looks a lot worse than the original image.

What I really want is this:

**Question:** Is there a way to take every pixel with x% blackness and 100-x% whiteness and turn it into a black pixel with x% opacity?

Example picture below:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried *Colors > Color to Alpha*?   It would be easier to help here if you were to share an example of the image. Also when adding an image as a texture, you often don't need to delete white pixels at all. Just change the layer blending mode to Multiply.

Comment: Thanks! I think colour to alpha works well for me and answers my question. And thanks for letting me know about multiply, although that's not exactly what I was looking for since I want to combine these translucent texture files in Inkscape.

Comment: You can use a Multiply blend mode in Inkscape too!